# datagridview cell end edit not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with quantity and price and net price. By default quantity is 1 and the relevant price is there. I want to edit the quantity so net price will come according to that. For e.g if I edit quantity to 2 the  netprice will come for 2. it will take price from price column and calculate

Here's my code.

```
 private void grvItems_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grvItems.Rows)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == grvItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index)
            {
                grvItems.EndEdit();
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Amt"].Value);
                decimal netprice = (quantity * price);
                row.Cells["netprice"].Value = Math.Round((netprice), 2);
            }


        }
        CalculateTotal();

    }
```

But the evnt is not firing. If i edit quantity, the net price is not relflected. Please suggest ideas.

Comment: Had you bind the event method to the form control?

Comment: `CellEndEdit` event triggers only after changes are completed, means focus move to other cell or any control.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch means I have to bind grvItems_CellEndEdit in form_load?

Comment: @HariPrasad Sorry I'm newbie, How can I rephrase the code then?

Comment: It seems you forgot to register the handler for the event. You can do it using code or using designer. **Using code** put the code after `InitializeComponent` in constructor: `grvItems.CellEndEdit+=grvItems_CellEndEdit;`. **Using designer**  select `grvItems`, go to property window, choose events tab, find `CellEndEdit` and choose `grvItems_CellEndEdit` from dropdown.

Comment: @RezaAghaei These things are already done. But event not firing :(

Comment: By the way, you should not ask a single question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267985/datagridview-cell-end-edit-event-not-working).

Comment: Do you leave the cell and check if the event fires?

Comment: @RezaAghaei How to leave cell. The focus is on the cell even after editing and hitting enter

Comment: So probably you have a validation error.

Comment: validation error as in?

Comment: Press TAB for lost focus and firing cellendedit

Answer (score 0):

Your change will reflect only after the cell will lost focus.
If you want to see the change during the edit, you can use the other event:

```
dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit
```

You can get help from MSDN, there is a good and simple example there: [CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit(v=vs.110).aspx)

**UPDATE**

As already mentioned, let's ensure you have registered your events.
In your form constructor, write as following:

```
public Form1()  // Constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        grvItems.CellBeginEdit += grvItems_CellBeginEdit;
        grvItems.CellEndEdit += grvItems_CellEndEdit;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

It is hard to help you in that way. I have created a similar example. Open a new Windows Form application, paste the following code. 
You need to add a DataGridView on the form (Form1).
This example is working fine. After doing it, try to see what are the differences with your code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")); // You can change it to Int32
        dt.Columns.Add("Amt", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
        dt.Columns.Add("netprice", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));

        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Quantity"] = 1;
        row["Amt"] = 2.5;
        row["netprice"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Quantity"].Index)
            {
                dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Amt"].Value);
                decimal netprice = (quantity * price);
                row.Cells["netprice"].Value = Math.Round((netprice), 2);
            }
        }


        // My suggestion:
        // No need to go through all the rows, just the current one
        /*
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Quantity"].Index)
        {
            // dataGridView1.EndEdit(); // No need this line, you are already in CellEndEdit event

            var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow.Cells["Amt"].Value);
            decimal netprice = (quantity * price);
            currentRow.Cells["netprice"].Value = Math.Round((netprice), 2);
        }
        */
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: How to lose focus? Please guide. I have already tried in cellbeginedit. Doesnt work

Comment: I you tried in cellbeginedit, so it is not a matter of lost focus. I update my answer. Let's try it and if not working, we will continue to fins the problem

Comment: Events are registered. Also focus is remaining on discount cell when i input and enter.

Comment: Do other DataGridView events are firing?

Comment: Yes others are firing

Comment: Can you post your DataGridView section in InitializeComponent()?

Comment: How can i leave the cell after i hit enter after inputting the discount? I think  due to that

Comment: even if I hit enter, the same cell is highlighted,.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the CellValueChanged event as an alternative to CellEndEdit and see if it does what you want.

Also, consider having the DataGridView do most of the work:

```
public partial class AlternativeToCellEndEdit : Form
{
    public AlternativeToCellEndEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
    }
    // Try handling CellValueChanged instead of CellEndEdit
    private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Our MyRecord class is smart and makes the calculation
        // any time we change Quantity or Amt. Here, we only need 
        // to refresh the DataGridView to show the updated info.
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
    // Make a class to represent a line item in the DataGridView.
    // When the Quantity or Amt changes, it recalculates itself.
    class MyRecord
    {
        public string Description { get; set; } = "New Item";
        int mQuantity = 1;
        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return mQuantity; }
            set { mQuantity = value;  NetPrice = Quantity * Amt; }  // Recalc
        }
        double mAmt = 0.00;
        public double Amt
        {
            get { return mAmt; }
            set { mAmt = value; NetPrice = Quantity * Amt; }        // Recalc
        }
        public double NetPrice { get; private set; } // Makes this cell Read-Only in the DataGridView
    }
    // Tell the DataGridView that we want to display our custom class.
    BindingList<MyRecord> Items = new BindingList<MyRecord>();
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        // Bind data to the view.
        // Now DataGridView does all the work for us.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Items;
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // Make everything look nice in the way of formatting.
        DataGridViewColumn col;
        col = dataGridView1.Columns["Description"];
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        col = dataGridView1.Columns["Quantity"];
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        col = dataGridView1.Columns["Amt"];
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2";
        col = dataGridView1.Columns["NetPrice"];
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2";

        // Add the first default item
        Items.Add(new MyRecord());
    }
}
```

[image]